# how to obtain list of tables in an access mdb database with C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Retrieve List of Tables in MS Access File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699897/retrieve-list-of-tables-in-ms-access-file) 
>   [How can I get a list of tables in an Access (Jet) database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152545) 
>   [Finding Tables in MS Access using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858824) 
>   [What is the OleDb equivalent for INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117974)

Is there a way to obtain the list of all tables in an.mdb file along with their associated row counts?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
con.Open();
DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] {null, null, null, "TABLE"});

for (int i=0;i< dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
MessageBox.Show( dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
}
con.Close();
```