# Accessing the Schema of an Access 2013 database

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office, oledb

If I try to read the schema of a Access 2013 database I receive the following error :

```
no read permission on 'MSysRelationships'
```

Now the help tells me that

```
User-level security features are not available in Access apps, web databases, 
or databases that use one of the new file formats (.accdb, .accde, .accdc, .accdr).
```

=> How can I read the schema of that DB ?

Edit :

here is my code in Linqpad :

```
var stringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
stringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
stringBuilder.DataSource = @"C:\Recommendations.accdb";

using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(stringBuilder.ToString().Dump()))
{
    connection.Open();
    var schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] {null, null, null, "TABLE"});
    var sheetName = schemaTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME")).First();
    schemaTable.Dump();

    string  namesQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT szRelationship, szReferencedObject, szObject FROM MSysRelationships";
    string  namesQuery2 =  string.Format("select Name, Age from [{0}]", "Users");

    using (var command = new OleDbDataAdapter(namesQuery, connection))
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        command.Fill(dataSet, sheetName);
        dataSet.Dump();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What mechanism are you using to try and "read the schema"? FWIW, I just typed `SELECT * FROM MSysRelationships` into the SQL pane of an Access_2013 query and it worked fine.

Comment: those new interface really have me lost. I cant even see where SQL Pane would be located.....

Comment: I can access the MSysResources through the Gui once I set the hidden tables to show (File / Options / Current Database / Navigation Options)

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the responses to a similar earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152545/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-tables-in-an-access-jet-database), I suspect that you simply cannot directly read the system tables in Access via an OleDb connection. However, you might be able to get the information you need via the `OleDbConnection.GetSchema` method (details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135983.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

In the Connection string, set 'User Id=Admin'.

Open the database with Access, and Ctrl-G to get the 'Immediate' window, and then execute the following command:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "GRANT SELECT ON MSysRelationships TO Admin;"
```

This will give 'User ID' permission to read (SELECT) from that table.
The same applies to the other system tables, like 'MSysObjects'.

Comment: This did the trick for querying system tables using packages DBI/ODBC in R