# pypyodbc get relationship between MS Access Tables

Tags: python, ms-access, pypyodbc

When reading an MS Access db with several tables with relationships between them, can pypyodbc read the relationship between the tables?

Comment: It depends... Were the relationships documented within Access using the Relationships tool?  Then your ODBC driver will let you query Access' msysRelationships hidden table to retrieve what was documented inside that tool.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer Yes, the relationships are documented in Access. How do I query them with pypyodbc? Do you have a minimal example?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer To be clear: If I run `cursor.execut("SELECT * FROM MSysRelationships")` I get: `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysRelationships'.")`  
The same query works in Access

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15504588/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson I've seen that. When I try to execute `cursor.execute("GRANT SELECT ON MSysRelationships TO Admin")` I get `[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124087/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson Can I do this in python from pyodbc? Or would I have to use another interface?

Comment: You can't do it with ODBC, but you can use Python to retrieve the information by inspecting the ACE.DAO `Relations` collection as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68591019/2144390).