# Displaying DataTable containing DB tables names

Tags: c#, .net

I've been trying to get an access tables names in c#, using:

```
m_cnADONewConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
Source=test.mdb";
m_cnADONewConnection.Open();
DataTable userTables = m_cnADONewConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
```

But don't know how to show only the tables names...any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Add list of table names to string list
List<string> names = new List<string>();
for (int i=0; i < userTables.Rows.Count; i++)
    names.Add(userTables.Rows[i][2].ToString());
```

I took this from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152545/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-tables-in-an-access-jet-database).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response by the way.

Comment: I guess that's up to you.  You could write them out to the console with `Console.WriteLine(userTable.Rows[i][2].ToString());`  Or you could add them to a listbox or other UI element if that's what you need.

Comment: Done...simply name[0] for example...You deserve a big green check mark!